# Pandas: Compare dataframe with csv file and update the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have below ddataframe

```
          domain   hostname      ip address  status           managed by      monitor target name
0         jetty.com  aabb   XXX.XX.XX.XXX         Deployed  Sec Team  aabb.jetty.com
1         jetty.com  axcd   XXX.XX.XX.XXX         Deployed  Sec Team  axcd.jetty.com
```

Now I have another csv file reporst.csv

```
"domain","hostname","ip address","managed by", "monitor target name"
"jetty.com","aabb","XXX.XX.XX.XXX", "Decreased","OP Team", "aabb.jetty.com"
"jetty.com","axcd","XXX.XX.XX.XXX", "Decreased","OP2 Team", "axcd.jetty.com"
"jetty.com","appd","XXX.XX.XX.XXX", "Dec","OP8 Team", "appd.jetty.com"
```

Now I want to compare the df to this csv and then update the csv to the below

```
"domain","hostname","ip address","managed by", "monitor target name"
"jetty.com","aabb","XXX.XX.XX.XXX", "Deployed","OP Team", "aabb.jetty.com"
"jetty.com","axcd","XXX.XX.XX.XXX", "Deployed","OP Team", "axcd.jetty.com"
"jetty.com","appd","XXX.XX.XX.XXX", "Dec","OP8 Team", "appd.jetty.com"
```

Now it is updated and look same as it is in the df

How can I update the csv according to the df value but not tough the other rows in the csv which are there already

I have the code

```
     newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hh, orient="index")
     exdf= pd.read_csv("./reports.csv")
     df1=newdf.set_index(['hostname'])
     df2=exdf.set_index(['hostname'])
     df2.update(df1)
```

getting error: KeyError: "None of ['hostname'] are in the columns"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with specified columns in both `DataFrame`s for match and create index from them:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('reporst.csv')

df1 = ddataframe.set_index(['domain','hostname','ip address'])
df2 = reporst.set_index(['domain','hostname','ip address'])

df2.update(df1)

df2.to_csv('out.csv')
```

If is not specified column for match and need match by positions, it means first row from first `DataFrame` by first row from another one, same logic for all rows use:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(hh, orient="index")
exdf= pd.read_csv("./reports.csv")

exdf.update(newdf)
```

Comment: but hostname, ip address, domain always might not be present and I do not know what ddataframe will get

Comment: @RajarshiDas - So how is possible match between?

Comment: So what is the unique key to compare? Can you define the "update"? What if an existing value is changed for example what happens when `managed by` related to `axcd` is changed to `LMN Team` instead of existing value? Do you want this update also?

Comment: I am getting the error KeyError: "None of ['hostname', 'domain', 'ip address'] are in the columns"

Comment: unique key is hostname

Comment: @RajarshiDas - OK, so if no columns `['hostname', 'domain', 'ip address']` so what is logic there? Can you add some example to question? Or  need match first row from df2 by first row by `ddataframe`, sam eway second row...? Is it possible?

Comment: yes I have updated the logic write by me in the question

Comment: OK, how working `exdf.update(newdf)` ? Are output correct? It is if possible logic one comment above

Comment: here it update the reports.csv with row wise update as well exdf.T.to_csv('reports.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=False)

Comment: @RajarshiDas - unfortunately not understand.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael for now its getting update using exdf.update(newdf)

Comment: on more issue if exdf has much column and data than newdf then exdf.update(newdf) work else oppsite case let say newdf has much data than exdf then its not working any thoughts you have ??

Comment: @RajarshiDas - a bit busy, is possible create new question?